How can I prevent "adjusting" for pod2man?
I wrote a perl-pod manual page that looked correct under perldoc:

But when I converted it to PostScript via pod2man and groff -Tps -man, the SYNOPSIS was "block-adjusted", adding a lot of space between the options:

How can I tell POD not to "adjust" a part of the manual page?
The relevant POD source for the section shown is (obviously) this:
=head1 SYNOPSIS

B<ldap-user-check>
[B<--account-context=>I<context>]
[B<--account-filter=>I<filter>]
[B<--default-notification-email-address=>I<email-addr>]
[B<--ca-certs-path=>I<path>]
[B<--credentials-file-name=>I<filename>]
[B<--ldap-size-limit=>I<number>]


According to a related question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/781914/320598) this seems to be the answer:
Yo can insert spacial commands (either for "roff" or "man") using the =for POD command like this:

=begin roff

.\" your roff commands go here

=end roff


Or specific for the question, save the adjust mode, then disable it, and later re-enable it, like this:

=pod

...

=head1 SYNOPSIS

=begin roff

.\" BEGIN roff
.\" save adjustment, then left-adjust
.ds _A \n[.j]
.ad l
.\" END roff

=end roff

Here your command and the many options follow...

=begin roff

.\" BEGIN roff
.\" restore saved adjustment
.ad \*(_A
.\" END roff

=end roff

=head1 DESCRIPTION

Blabla...

=cut


In pod2man output the contents if the block will be inserted like this:
.\" ...
.SH "SYNOPSIS"
.IX Header "SYNOPSIS"
.\" BEGIN roff
.\" save adjustment, then left-adjust
.ds _A \n[.j]
.\" END roff
.\" ...
.\" BEGIN roff
.\" restore saved adjustment
.ad \*(_A
.\" END roff
.SH "DESCRIPTION"
.IX Header "DESCRIPTION"
.\" ...

